# JavaScript event handler with iframe

Tags: javascript

I got a site that loads multiple recaptcha at once in iframes.
I was wondering when a user hit enter after typing the captcha if there a way to add a key event to toggle to the next iframe box and enter the next recaptcha?
Most of the site is written in php but there are some stuff javascript added

Comment: Multiple recaptchas? Sounds fishy.

Comment: So out of interest why do you present multiple captchas to a user? Surly one captcha is enough to establish that this is a real user?

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off using a different recaptcha method that doesn't require the use of iframes. Finding a work-around for the iframe security sandbox, if even possible, may be more work then it's worth.

Comment: Or have each recaptcha at a different URL so you can just change the URL of the iframe each time you want to advance.